# How to move nth column to first column in SQL table while dealing with NULL values?

Tags: sql

I have a table of employees and managers that I am trying to set up in a hierarchical order. At the moment I have employee in the first column, their manager, their manager's manager, and so on. I'd like to reverse this table so the highest ranking person(CEO) is the first column, the manager under them, and so on until the employee. If there are only 3 people ahead of that person then the last 4 columns will be NULL.

Coalesce gets close, but it will fill NULL columns with the same manager multiple times. For example, if an employee only has 3 managers above them, it will put the CEO 5 times before filling out the next in line.

```
SELECT 
Employee,
COALESCE(Manager9,Manager8,Manager7,Manager6,Manager5,Manager4,Manager3,Manager2,Manager1) AS [Manager 1],
COALESCE(Manager8,Manager7,Manager6,Manager5,Manager4,Manager3,Manager2,Manager1) AS [Manager 2],
COALESCE(Manager7,Manager6,Manager5,Manager4,Manager3,Manager2,Manager1) AS [Manager 3],
COALESCE(Manager6,Manager5,Manager4,Manager3,Manager2,Manager1) AS [Manager 4],
COALESCE(Manager5,Manager4,Manager3,Manager2,Manager1) AS [Manager 5],
COALESCE(Manager4,Manager3,Manager2,Manager1) AS [Manager 6],
COALESCE(Manager3,Manager2,Manager1) AS [Manager 7],
COALESCE(Manager2,Manager1) AS [Manager 8],
Manager1 AS [Manager 9]


FROM #Temp
```

I'd like this to say the top manager first (CEO), then that direct report to them, and so on until the employee comes up. The employee could be in the 2nd column or the 9th, and will fill NULLs in after that.

Comment: Rather unusual hierarchy design. Provide sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit hard to visualize without data.  If I understand correctly, you can use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT Employee,
       COALESCE(Manager9, Manager8, Manager7,Manager6, Manager5, Manager4, Manager3, Manager2, Manager1) AS [Manager 1],
       (CASE WHEN [Manager 2] IS NOT NULL
             THEN COALESCE(Manager8, Manager7,Manager6, Manager5, Manager4, Manager3, Manager2, Manager1)
        END) AS [Manager 2],
       (CASE WHEN [Manager 3] IS NOT NULL
             THEN COALESCE(Manager7,Manager6, Manager5, Manager4, Manager3, Manager2, Manager1)
        END) AS [Manager 3],
       . . .
FROM #Temp t;
```